# Service Messaging is not available in FCM v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]

This error is occurring whenever I save the firebase.js config file.
I'm not being able to use Firebase Cloud Messaging in Firebase V9.

my firebase.js config

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID,
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore();
const storage = getStorage();
const messaging = getMessaging(app); // error on this line

export { app, db, storage, messaging };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turns out its because of firebase v9 in Nextjs.

The solution is to downgrade your firebase version to v8.

Notice that firebase v8 has a different syntax than v9.

To change to [for example] v8.10 you will first need to uninstall your current firebase version:

```
npm uninstall firebase
```

and then add firebase v8.10:

```
npm i firebase@8.10.0
```